# Edit rejected, for adding extra information beyond single-character typo

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I attempted to edit an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19575146) to fix a broken Wikipedia anchor. Since I get the error "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?", I tried adding extra information missing from the answer. My edit got rejected as a result.

As a result, I am put into a catch-22 where I cannot fix the URL without "unwanted" changes to the remaining post.

Comment: For the future, a way around this would have been to refactor the link to `[text](url)`

Answer (score -4):

> My edit got rejected as a result.

No, your edit was the result of two people who seem to have difficulty understanding the difference between "addressing the author of the post" and "adding more information". Your information was clearly not addressed to the author of the post, so it should not have been rejected for that reason.

But since that mistake has happened, I'd suggest making a comment on the post, telling its owner that the link is broken and what it should be.

Comment: It appears a high-reputation user has done a single-character edit anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9133865/revisions

Comment: I disagree, the edit introduced text that should have been posted as an answer of their own (which is included in the "addressing the author of the post" decline reason). It shouldn't have been edited in.

Comment: @jimbo1qaz Not just a high-reputation user, but a moderator.

Comment: @jimbo1qaz The 6 characters limit exists primarily to reduce the number of edits sent to suggested edit review queue. Users with 2k+ reputation, who do not have their edits sent to the queue, are not subject to the limit.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time interpreting what's not agreeable of this answer... is what, despite my best efforts, is recommended to do in this situation...

Comment: @Braiam because it says *it should not have been rejected*. I personally am with Mark, in that it should have been rejected, as it added extra information.

Comment: @CalvT: I said, "it should not have been rejected ***for that reason***". I didn't say that there weren't other reasons that might have been used to reject it.

Comment: @NicolBolas fair enough, but as it stands, your answer is basically saying that that kind of edit (adding extra text) is ok. You might want to address that.

Comment: @CalvT: I don't know if I would classify what was done as "extra information" rather than "clarifying information", which is perfectly valid. I'm not a domain expert in that sort of thing.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Your interpretation of the rejection reason clearly differs drastically from mine and Nicol's. The text *"Additionally, browsers other than Internet Explorer will not send such "host-only cookies" to subdomains of the page requested."* clearly does not make sense as a standalone answer (and wouldn't even be entirely clear as a comment on this one), but *does* make sense in place in the prose it was edited into. As such, I'm with Nicol that it's a misuse of the *"should have been written as a comment or an answer"*. reason. *"Conflicts with author's intent"* *might* be valid.

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm not saying I would have chosen that reason, but I do understand **why** it was chosen, so I disagree with Nicolas' assertion that it shouldn't have been chosen (specifically because the description includes _"should have been written as [..] an answer"_). If the OP thought the information was relevant (and I don't think it is), he should have posted his own detailing that. Putting it in an answer of another user is not the right way in my opinion.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Since when has adding information to an answer not been a valid edit? As long as it isn't taking over the post, contradicting the intent of the post, and is not incorrect, I don't recall any specific rule that says that such edits are not OK. I've certainly made some, and I've had some made on my posts. There's little point in repeating 90% of an answer just to add 10% more. Especially if that 10% is not critical to the answer.

Comment: As far as I am aware, changing the scope of a non-community-wiki answer (which this edit was) has always been seen as something that should be viewed with suspicion and err on the side of rejection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Adding information is not "changing the scope". Not unless you're adding so much information that the scope is changed. And I don't see how the sentence in question does that.